# Does user data need to be sanitised before running console.log?

Tags: node.js, security, user-input, console.log, sanitization

I have a NodeJS backend that receives some user data which will be stored in a database. Currently it is not being sanitised anywhere.

Are there any risks in writing it directly to the console with `console.log`? If so, what is a reasonable way to sanitise it?

Comment: What exactly is the concern here? For example very large (think megabytes and megabytes) user data might stall the program while it's being written to the log. The sanitisation there is basically not possible, unless you just truncate it. Or the user might do log forging and supply data that includes parts that are intended to fool you are part of the real logs of the application. Presumably to lead you to false conclusions and hide some other activity. There are ways to ensure proper log verification then without needing to sanitise the input.

Comment: "What exactly is the concern?" - I don't know. Basically, I'm asking "what's the worst that could possibly be happen if I console.log random user input".

Comment: As I said: DoS if writing the logs is expensive. Especially large text. But if your user input is something like 100 characters, that's probably not a concern. Same with the log forging - it needs very meticulously crafted attack to pull off. And the chance of that is slim. It is also easily thwarted if...you don't look at the logs. However, who knows - maybe you have other tools parsing and acting on the logs. Depending on what they do and how, there might be some malicious input that affects those tools. Maybe you don't *yet* use something like this but later you add a log monitor ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Cool, so "sanitising" it by truncating to a reasonable length is probably enough for most cases.

Comment: Probably. Honestly, if you're truncating anyway, why even print it? I suppose you could then verify it's 1. non-empty 2. sort of starts reasonable. As opposed to maybe being gibberish. But still calls into question why you'd need that user input shown.